# How to convert PowerPoint (.ppt) to PDF in Java

Tags: itext

Only last slide is getting convert means last slide overlapping every slides. Can anyone suggest how to combine it in one PDF?

I have tried with different approach but they are first creating image and then PDF.

```java
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(in);
SlideShow ppt = new SlideShow(inputStream);
inputStream.close();
Dimension pgsize = ppt.getPageSize();
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(out));
document.setPageSize(new Rectangle(
        (float)pgsize.getWidth(), (float)pgsize.getHeight()));
document.open();
PdfGraphics2D graphics= null;
for (int i = 0; i < ppt.getSlides().length; i++) {
    Slide slide = ppt.getSlides()[i];
    graphics = (PdfGraphics2D) pdfWriter.getDirectContent()
            .createGraphics((float)pgsize.getWidth(), (float)pgsize.getHeight());
    slide.draw(graphics);
}
graphics.dispose();
document.close();
```

Comment: Is your question about `itext` or about `pdfbox`?

Comment: Why are you using [a 6.5 year old beta version of Apache POI with known security issues](http://poi.apache.org/devel/history/changes-3x.html#3.11-beta1)?

Comment: @Gagravarr My project has so many old dependencies so when I update anything I get version conflicts. I will try to update dependencies.

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse itext or pdfbox anything will be fine.

Comment: Your code appears to be using iText classes, and no PDFBox classes, so there is no use in adding the `pdfbox` tag. I'll edit your question.

Comment: I've implemented PDF rendering in the current snapshot, which will be released soon. Check ["instructions to run"](http://poi.apache.org/components/slideshow/ppt-wmf-emf-renderer.html) to test it. and then `pdfbox` tag applies again.